# passing the input values into Apex controller method

Tags: lightning-web-components

I could able to upload the file successfully but the input value not passing through the method. Could you please help me on this.

JS:

```
import { LightningElement ,wire,track,api} from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CREDITCARD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_card__c';
import PROGRAMM_Field from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_card__c.Choose_Program_Reason__c';
import AXPID_Field from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_card__c.AX_PID__c';
//import EXCHANERATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_card__c.Exchange_Rate__c';
//import IMPORT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Credit_card__c.ImportId__c';

import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import insertdata from '@salesforce/apex/importdata.readCSVFileInsertMember';



export default class Uploadfilewithinput extends LightningElement {
  @api impnum ="";
    inpputnum="";
    Programvalue="";
    Avalue="";
    @track success;
    @track failure;
    @api recordId;

handlechange(event){
 this.impnum=event.target.value;
}

handlechange1(event){
this.inpputnum=event.target.value;
}
   @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CREDITCARD_OBJECT })
   objectInfo; 
   @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName:PROGRAMM_Field})
    Programvalues;
      @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName: AXPID_Field})
      AXvalues;

    @wire(insertdata , { impnum: '$impnum'})
    deWired;

      //inpputnum: '$inpputnum',Programvalue: '$Programvalue',Avalue: '$Avalue'

    handleselect(event){

       if(event.target.name ==='Program'){
          this.Programvalue=event.target.value;
     }
       if(event.target.name === 'AXvalue'){
           this.Avalue=event.target.value;
        }
}

get acceptedFormats() {

    return ['.csv'];
}

handleUploadFinished(event) {

    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
   insertdata({idContentDocument : uploadedFiles[0].documentId}) 

    .then(result => {

      this.success = result;  
     this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
           title: 'Success!!',
            message: 'Campaign Members are created based CSV file!!!',
    variant: 'success',
        }),
    );

    })

    .catch(error => {
        this.failure=error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
              title: 'Error!!',
                message: JSON.stringify(error),
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );     

   });

}

}
```

Controller:

```
public class importdata{

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<Campaignmember> readCSVFileInsertMember(Id idContentDocument,string impnum ){


    List<Campaignmember> lstCampaignMembers = new List<Campaignmember>();
        if(idContentDocument != null) {
            ContentVersion objVersion = [Select Id,VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId =: idContentDocument][0];

            if(objVersion != null) {

            Blob csvFileBody =objVersion.VersionData;
               String csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();

                String[] csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 



                for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
                    Campaignmember  camobj = new Campaignmember() ;
                    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                    camobj.CampaignId= csvRecordData[0] ;             
                    camobj.ContactId= csvRecordData[1];
                    camobj.Status= csvRecordData[2];
                    camobj.impnum__c=impnum;

                    lstCampaignMembers.add(camobj );   
                }

                if(!lstCampaignMembers.isEmpty()) {
                    insert lstCampaignMembers;
                }
                }
                }

        return lstCampaignMembers;

        }
   }

HTML

<template>
    <lightning-card icon-name="custom:custom19" title='Credit card information uplaod'>
<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-medium"> 
<lightning-input type="number" name="Import Id"  required label="Import Id"  value={impnum} 
        onclick={handlechange} style="width:200px">
            </lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </div>
 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-medium"> 
                 <template if:true={Programvalues.data}>
                     <lightning-combobox
                     name="Program" label="Program" value={Programvalue}  placeholder="-Select-" options={Programvalues.data.values}
                     onchange={handleselect} style="width:200px"></lightning-combobox>
                 </template>
             </lightning-layout-item>
         </div>
         <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-medium"> 
        <template if:true={AXvalues.data}>
                        <lightning-combobox 
                        name="AXvalue" label="AxPID" value={Avalue} placeholder="-Select-"   options={AXvalues.data.values}
                        onchange={handleselect}  style="width:200px" ></lightning-combobox>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-medium"> 
                                <lightning-input type="number" name="Exchange Rate"  required label="Exchange Rate"  value={inpputnum} 
                                onclick={handlechange1} style="width:200px" >
                  </lightning-input>
                   </lightning-layout-item>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <lightning-file-upload name="Import Data" label="Import Data" accept={acceptedFormats}  record-id={recordId}
                        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} ></lightning-file-upload>
                        <template if:true ={success} >
                        <c-error-panel errors={success}></c-error-panel>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={failure}>
                        <c-error-panel errors={failure}></c-error-panel>
                        </template>
                        </lightning-card>
                         </template>
```

Comment: So your documentId is null or your SOQL query returns empty Body?

Comment: There is no problem with the Document id  .The problem with the camobj.impnum__c=impnum;

Value is not passing along with the other fileds like Status,ContactId,CampaignId

Comment: you never set 'impnum'. And call this method only with DocumentId where in the code you are passing file Content to Apex?

Comment: for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
                    Campaignmember  camobj = new Campaignmember() ;
                    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                    camobj.CampaignId= csvRecordData[0] ;             
                    camobj.ContactId= csvRecordData[1];
                    camobj.Status= csvRecordData[2];
                    camobj.impnum__c=impnum;

                    lstCampaignMembers.add(camobj );   
                }

Comment: where do you pass this value from LWC to Apex?

Comment: This is the input value and passing using wire method

@wire(insertdata , { impnum: '$impnum'})
    deWired;

Comment: Yes, but this value is not set anywhere in the component and handlechange also not used in your template

Comment: Some how Th code is not displaying correctly here but  i have  defined in HTML template and also handle methods in JS
<lightning-input type="number" name="Import Id"  required label="Import Id"  value={impnum} 
        onclick={handlechange} style="width:200px">

Comment: i have added HTML now in the end of the contoller

Comment: you need to wrap separate parts of your code into ``` ``` ```in order to show it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change
`insertdata({idContentDocument : uploadedFiles[0].documentId})` to `insertdata({idContentDocument : uploadedFiles[0].documentId, impnum: this.impnum})`, so that you actually pass the number when you call.

Theoretically, your method is also being called with wire, but in the wired call, you don't pass Documentid.

Comment: I have tried above method and verified  the debug logs the impnum is blank hence the value is not processing as input

Comment: you use `onclick` handler for lightning-input. change it to `onkeypress`

Comment: Thank you for helping me . Its working aft changing from onclick to onkeypress

Comment: One more question the file upload is enabling  in  record page but not on app pa it is disabled.

do you know the reason

Comment: @SivaKummar because lightning-file-upload attaches files to records, so it'll uses recordId from your Record Page

Comment: Thanks for  providing the answer.
After uploading data trying to upload again getting below error.
 [t[Yn] is not a function]
I did  verify the  debug logs and it is success but in UI it is showing error

Comment: You need to debug it. Something is missing in your JS

Comment: I tried a lot change in JS but i did not figure out the issue. Could you please help where exactly i need to check in JS?